# Смена панелей во время исполнения прграммы

Tags: swing

```
public class Frame {

    private JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("<test> BattleSea </test>");
    public FieldComp fieldComp = new FieldComp();
    public FieldPlayer fieldPlayer = new FieldPlayer();
    private MidPaneStart midPaneStart = new MidPaneStart();
    private MidPaneGame midPaneGame = new MidPaneGame();
    private ImageIcon imageComp = new ImageIcon("comp.png");
    private ImageIcon imagePlayer = new ImageIcon("player.png");
    private ImageIcon imageStart = new ImageIcon("startP.png");

    public Frame(){

        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1100,485));
        jFrame.setLocation(350,200);
        jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jFrame.setResizable(false);

        jFrame.getContentPane().add(fieldComp.getPane(),BorderLayout.EAST);
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(fieldPlayer.getPane(),BorderLayout.WEST);

        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        int i = (int)(Math.random()*2+1);
        setHod(i);
        midPaneStart.getTablo().setIcon(imageStart);
        setMidPane("2");
    }

    public void setHod(int i){

        if (i == 1) {
            midPaneGame.getTablo().setIcon(imageComp);
        } else {
            midPaneGame.getTablo().setIcon(imagePlayer);
        }
    }

    public void setMidPane(String w){
        switch (w){
            case "1":
                System.out.println(1);
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(midPaneStart.getMidPaneStart(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out.println(2);
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(midPaneGame.getMidPaneGame(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
                break;
            case "3":
                jFrame.getContentPane().remove(2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

По нажатию кнопки нужна смена панелек, но они не меняются. Если нажать на кнопку `Remove` - панель просто перестает реагировать. Из других классов вызываю метод через статический инстант в `main`. Отклик есть, т.е. панельки меняются (удаляютя) когда растягиваешь окно, а так как будто замирает.

Comment: Где функция при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: setMidPane вызывается через статический фрейм в мейне - Main.frame.setMidPane

Answer (score 1):

Для таких вещей, как смена панелей, есть специальный layout [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: спасибо. Хотелось бы еще узнать почему все таки тормозит в этом случае.

Comment: показывайте код, посмотрим. тормозить ничего не должно.

Comment: Сегодня к сожалению не могу, завтра покажу

Comment: извиняюсь, я оказывается забыл, что уже поменял код на CardLayout (кста удобней) и не сохранил старый вариант.